# iAd "no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:"

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard, iad

I ran my app with wifi disabled and I always get white space and this message in the debugger:

ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x9632d30 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}

Please help me fix my code:
.h

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GameCenterManagerDelegate , ADBannerViewDelegate> {


//iAD
ADBannerView *banner;  
 }

//iAD
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ADBannerView *banner;
```

.m

```
@synthesize  banner , bannerIsVisible;
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)abanner {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, 50.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)aBanner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0.0, -50.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}

}
```

Comment: Did u got solution to this ? I am facing same problem as well. Given delegate though console says that.

Answer (score 6):

As per the delegate portion of the error. In your viewDidLoad (or wherever you initialize) method set `banner.delegate = self;`

Comment: Well now when i run with a valid connection the banner is completely hidden and the debugger gives me this: "ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0xb259210) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view."    But when i run with no connection it does hide itself properly with no problems. Any Ideas as to whats wrong?

Comment: You have to add the banner view to the view... something like this (in viewdidload again): `[self.view addSubview:banner];`

Comment: Is your banner at the top or bottom of your display? (Trying to verify the offset stuff you're doing; possible the views are not visible after animation complete).. Can you paste your initialization code for your banner view, and its initial frame?

Comment: My app is having same thing. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ui-maker-design-mobile-app/id791072042?mt=8 . I have applied the Delegate methods of iAds to show when First Ad is loaded, until then I am keeping iAds Hidden. I have checked all the delegate methods... I am getting Ads in Developer certificates but not on Final Appstore version.... What could be the reason??

Answer (score 2):

Completely new to iOS development, but I believe you need to set the adBanner view delegate in the storyboard. To do this right click the adBanner and drag to files owner. Then select delegate. This solved this issue for me :).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the delegate in interface Builder (IB).  Otherwise when the view loads there is no delegate assigned and you will get this error message.